# SED command to format text file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to create a SED command to modify an input file with some conditions explained below.

I have an input file something like below.

List item

```
Rad# ; ID_KEY ; UNIT_ID
1  ; 30000000004 ; 8417920 
2  ; 30000000004 ; 8170811 
         ︙
10  ; 30000000004 ; 1581292
           ︙
1001  ; 3000000000 ; 8285052
```

Below are few things I need to do with this file:

1. Remove 1st line completely
2. Retain only 2nd and 3rd number group separated by comma
3. Append string `,DATABASE` at the end of each line.

The output should look something like below.

List item

```
30000000004,8417920,DATABASE
30000000004,8170811,DATABASE
```

Comment: This is a job that is more suitable to be done by `awk`. Off top of my mind  `awk -F';'  'BEGIN{OFS=",";} NR>1{ print $2,$3,"DATABASE"}' filename`

Comment: That works!! But I also want to remove the white spaces in my result. Currently it's printing something like 
' 3000000004 , 8417,DATABASE' I need it to be 300000004,8417,DATABASE without any spaces.

Comment: I posted the answer which removes leading whitespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the output in the question is the  desired output, you can try this.

```
awk -F';'  'BEGIN{OFS=",";} NR>1{gsub(/ /,""); print $2,$3,"DATABASES"}' filename | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/,/;ta'
```

Probably this could be accomplished with `awk` only.  Remove the `sed` part if you want lines in the same row.

Since SE seems to be having educative purposes, I'll do my best to explain what each flag on the above command does.

`-F';'` # Uses `;` as `--field-separator`
`BEGIN {OFS=",";}` # This is a special pattern which runs prior any command that follows and it's output is not influenced by the rest of the program. Then we have `ORS`

`ORS` # Since the output should include a comma `,` we define the `Output Record Separator` to have comma as a value. The default value of `ORS` is a new line `"\n"`

`NR>1` # Here we say to skip the first record. `NR` is also a special reserved variable that holds the total number of input records.

`gsub()` # Is a function which accepts a few parameters. If no field specified e.g `$2` or `$3` then `gsub()` function uses the entire record which is `$0`

Finally  `print $2,$3,"DATABASE"` will print the specified fields and adds `DATABASE` at the end of the line.

`print $2,$3` # Here we use comma to separate fields. The default `FS (Field separator)` delimiter is a single blank space `' '`.

I hope this brief description clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming that you mean you want each line of input (after the header)
to translate into one line of output (and not all run together on one line,
as the first version of your question illustrated). 
`sed` is a very good tool for that job; it can be done as

```
sed -e 1d -e "s/.* ; \(.*\) ; \(.*[^ ]\) */\1,\2,DATABASE/" filename
```

where

- `1d` means delete the first line, and
- `s/.* ; \(.*\) ; \(.*[^ ]\) */\1,\2,DATABASE/`
  means break down every line (after the first) into
                  `something1 ; something2 ; something3`
  and then replace that with
                  `something2,something3,DATABASE` 
  The `.*[^ ]` part is to exclude any trailing spaces from `something3`.

Comment: Expressions can be separated by an `;`, there's no need for multiple `-e` switches. -e '1d;s/.* ; \(.*\) ; \(.*[^ ]\) */\1,\2,DATABASE/' will work as well

Comment: Yes, I know. Functionality is not the only goal here at Stack Exchange; we also strive for education and explanation. I thought it would be clearer to make the two commands separate — especially since semicolons appear ***within*** one of the commands.  And now let me teach you something: if you have only "expression" or "script", you can leave out the `-e`, so your suggestion is three characters longer than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

As in comments awk solution:

```
awk '{ FS=";"; OFS=","; gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2); gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $3); gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $3); } NR > 1 { print $2, $3, "DATABASE" }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do:

```
cut -d' ' -f3,5 <infile | 
sed -n 'y/ /,/;1!s/$/,DATABASE/p'
```

...as I think it is probably close the most efficient solution to this problem.