# How do I remove newline character from lines preceding a particular pattern?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
1
22
1
4
$3
3
5556
$33
$233
$1
5
```

I want to move all the lines starting with `$` to the previous line by replacing the newline characters with a space. My result should look something like:

```
1
22
1
4 $3
3
5556 $33 $233 $1
5
```

How can I do it using `sed` or `grep` or `awk`?

Comment: http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.26

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I tried this, but all that happens is a space gets inserted before lines with $. It's not working.

Answer (score 3):

A similar question is posted here: [SED command to format text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191393/sed-command-to-format-text-file/191398#191398)

As the comment of Stéphane suggest the solution to your question using `sed` would be as follow:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\$/ $/;ta' -e 'P;D' filename
```

Comment: I tried this, but all that happens is a space gets inserted before lines with $. It's not working.

Comment: @user110327, is it possible that your file be formatted as a MS-DOS text file with CRLF line delimiters? Try `dos2unix < filename | sed...` to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, you have to:

1. convert the text to hex
2. replace 0a24 (line feed and $) with 2024 (space and $)
3. convert it back to text

In this one-liner the file is called "file":

```
# xxd -ps file|tr -d "\n"|sed s/0a24/2024/g|xxd -r -ps
1
22
1
4 $3
3
5556 $33 $233 $1
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS = " "} {print}' file | sed 's/\( \)\([0-9]\)/\n\2/g'
```

`awk` changes the column into a row by setting the Output Field Separator to a space, while `sed` finds the `space+number` pattern and replaces it with a `newline+number` pattern.

Comment: Please note that it is rarely necessary to pipe the output of `grep` or `awk` into `sed` or vice versa; usually these programs are powerful enough to do the task completely on their own. Also, you are setting `ORS`, not `OFS` (as indicated in the explanation) to `space`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ vi file
:g/^\$/-1j
:x
```

I.e. do a one-line `:join` on the lines which precede dollar sign lines, then save and quit.